# Kubernetes preparing worker node running a job?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to set a `sysctl` setting on the nodes I run OpenSearch on.

**Pod**
I came up with the following `initContainer` solution.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: os-init-sysctl
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: os-init-sysctl
spec:
  containers:
  - name: os-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-sysctl
    image: busybox
    command:
    - sysctl
    - -w
    - vm.max_map_count=262144
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Sadly this is run on only one node and keeps running as the os-container is sleeping.

How to do this better and on all worker nodes without consuming resources afterwards? Can I have a pod just with an initContainer without a os-container, did not get this to work so far?

**DaemonSet**
I read about dameonset's but also concluded that they have to run consistently.Is this the case?

**Job**
What about a job? Could I run a job on every node? What